# Select Top1 from multiple-column query for each product ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQLServer that returns the last entry in our stock of a given product, as well as many other columns. Something like:

```
SELECT
TOP(1) EntryDate,
EntryPrice,
TaxID,
TransportCost,
...

FROM
StockEntries

WHERE
ProductID = @ID

ORDER BY
EntryDate DESC
```

I cannot use MAX to get the last entry because sometimes it returns duplicate rows (when there are two entries at the same day).

I would like to execute this query for every product we have. I could do this if the query returned only 1 row, such as:

```
SELECT
ProductID p,
(
    SELECT
    TOP(1) s.EntryDate

    FROM
    StockEntries s

    WHERE
    s.ProductID = p.ProductID

    ORDER BY
    s.EntryDate DESC
)

FROM
Products p
```

But as it returns multiple rows, I cannot see a straight way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have phrased the question, `cross apply` seems very appropriate:

```
SELECT p.*, s.*
FROM products p CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP(1) s.*
      FROM StockEntries s
      WHERE s.ProductID = p.ProductID
      ORDER BY s.EntryDate DESC
     ) s;
```

`APPLY` also allows you to select other columns from `StockEntries`.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use ROW_NUMBER() to rank each row and then just get the rows with the highest entry date per product.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT p.productid,
                s.EntryDate,
                s.EntryPrice,
                s.TaxID,
                s.TransportCost,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.productid ORDER BY s.entrydate DESC) rownum
         FROM   products p
                JOIN StockEntries s ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID
        ) t
WHERE   rownum = 1
```